# Создание файла "jpg" из массива картинок

Tags: java, jpeg

Есть массив маленьких картинок (обрезаных из одной фотографии)

```
BufferedImage[] image;
```

Вот так я достаю из него эти маленькие картинки и размещаю в `panel1`

```
for(int i=0; i< image.length; i++){

        pic = new ImageIcon(image[i]);  
        panel1.add(new JLabel(pic));

   }
```

Вот собственно метод, который создает эти маленькие картинки

```
 public BufferedImage[] getImage() {

        loadAndSplitImage(tilesetImage);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(row,col,1,1));

        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int q=0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

                tileset[q] = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
                tileset[q] = image.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);            

                x += width;
                q++;
            }// end for loop
            y += height;
            x = 0;
        }// end for loop

        return tileset;
      }
```

На подобии матрицы мне кажется надо будет что то делать... Только не могу дорубить как это сделать.

***Вопрос:***
Как реализовать упорядочивание этих маленьких картинок, что бы создалась из фрагментов одна большая картинка ?

То есть по сути мне нужно создать фон, и на нем упорядочить в нужном порядке маленькие фрагменты, что бы получилась картинка ? Если да, то от маленького примера не отказался бы.

***Для большей ясности прикладываю фото:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: @KromStern уточнил !

Comment: Стало лучше, но недостаточно. Как вы хотите манипулировать кусочками и на чем их разместить? То есть суть вопроса так и не ясна

Comment: Если я правильно понял, в массиве tileset по порядочку нарезки лежат Ваши картинки. По этому не совсем понятно, что вы подразумеваете под словом "упорядочивание", похоже что они и так у Вас упорядочены уже.

Comment: @IDrakonl они идут просто последовательностью 1,2,3,4..
а мне надо что бы было 0,0 0,1 0,2 1,1 1,2 1,3... что бы можно было собрать картинку. 
Допустим, есть изображение кота 1920 на 1080. При условии, что бы большой бок квадратика (которые получаю в результате нарезки) был равен около 512 пикселей их получится 16. 
Вот что относится к вопросу: как мне этих 16 квадратиков рассортировать так, что бы получилась картинка, а не полоска с квадратами. И ка кмне эти 16 отсортированных квадратов записать в файл jpg и изменить разрешение. (разрешение можно думаю будет в параметрах указать).

Comment: @KromStern вот выше написал, лучше уже не получится )

Comment: Из кода не понятно, откуда взяты `row` и `col`. Похоже, что они задаются за ранее или вычисляются.
В любом случае, похоже, что вы их знаете или можете получить известным вам способом.
Тогда снова не понятно, в чем проблема. Ваши картинки по порядку и пронумерованы по 1. Вопрос не как упорядочить, а как вывести?

Comment: @IDrakonl можете зайти в чат ? не хочу комментарии загрязнять )

Comment: Куда именно надо зайти?

Comment: @IDrakonl Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26073/discussion-between-kxxko-and-ldrakonl).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно что-то типа этого?

```
// на входе index от 0 до N

rowIndex = index div column_count; // целая часть от деления
colIndex = index mod column_count; // модуль

// на выходе пары (rowIndex, colIndex) от (0,0) до (x,y)
```

Comment: давайте чат, я вам покажу на примерах фотографий

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--